# Why can't I reassign the value of a pointer?

Tags: c++, qt, c++17

I am using a library for GUI (Qtitan for Qt).

There I have a class called `NavigationViewHeader` whose pointer I can access by `navigationView->header()`.

Now I want to reassign the content of the pointer, but it tells me (translated)

> The function "NavigationViewHeader::operator=(const NavigationViewHeader &)" (implicit declared)" cannot be referenced (it is a deleted function).

```
NavigationViewHeader newHeader(navigationView);
NavigationViewHeader* oldHeader = navigationView->header();

*oldHeader = newHeader;
```

Is it possible to reassign the value or does the framework maybe restrict this by themself? There Is no `= delete` function inside the framework-class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is a bit confusingly worded. `NavigationViewHeader` doesn't declare a copy assignment operator, which is why the compiler implicitly declares one. However, one of its base classes has a deleted assignment operator, so this fails.

I assume `NavigationViewHeader` inherits from `QObject` since you mentioned it being a Qt GUI. Those cannot be copy-assigned. See [here in the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator).

> QObject has neither a copy constructor nor an assignment operator. This is by design. Actually, they are declared, but in a private section with the macro Q_DISABLE_COPY(). In fact, all Qt classes derived from QObject (direct or indirect) use this macro to declare their copy constructor and assignment operator to be private. The reasoning is found in the discussion on Identity vs Value on the Qt Object Model page.

Side note: I think this part of the documentation is a bit outdated. Privating operators was a C++03 technique. They likely changed that macro to delete the method instead.

Comment: Yes you are right about the inheritance. I have to find a way around it probably since I cannot manipulate this pointer.

Comment: @Me3nTaL I assume there is no ```setHeader``` function or constructor argument?

Comment: No there is not. The problem is that I want my own instance of this `NavigationViewHeader` which I can configure by myself. The original instance is being created by the `NavigationView` which I cannot prevent.